# Spring Cloud Gateway: Rewriting URI in incoming requests

Tags: regex, spring-cloud-gateway

I am pretty new to Spring Cloud Gateway and rusty on my regex. I've googled around, but haven't found an answer to this. In fact, this is my first post on stackoverflow in a 20 yr career :)

I am trying to allow traffic into host1.com/enablement/requests and forward it to host2.com/enablement/request. Notice the lack of an s in the second URI. I haven't seen any examples of how to do this url rewrite. Is it because its a simple regex that I'm overlooking?

I've seen this in many examples. Can you explain what it is doing?

```
- RewritePath=/enablement/workflow(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
```

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: data_service_route
          uri: host2.com/enablement
          predicates:
            - Path=/enablement/requests
            - Method=POST,GET,PUT
          filters:
            - RewritePath=???
```

Any advice/example would be greatly appreciated.

Geoff

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with spring-cloud-gateway last couple of days, let me try and explain:

```
RewritePath=/enablement/workflow(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
```

There are 2 expressions here separated by the comma, a regex used for patterning matching and the replacement string.

`(?<segment>/?.*)` creates a named capturing group, the value will be stored under the key 'segment'

`$\{segment}` is the replacement string - in this example this will be the value of captured group segment. The backlash \ is required for escaping(yaml).

so `/enablement/workflow/endpoint` becomes `/endpoint`

A very basic code snippet below:

```
        String regexp = "/enablement/requests/(?<path>.*)";
        String replacement = "/enablement/request/${path}";
        String path = "hostname:port/enablement/requests/endpoint";

        System.out.println(path.replaceAll(regexp, replacement));
```

Below is a very useful link for refreshing regex:

https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Links to relevant spring-cloud-gateway classes below:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/main/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/route/builder/GatewayFilterSpec.java
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/main/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory.java